# excel function for divide or split number to maximum possible equal parts

Tags: excel, excel-formula, numbers, excel-2010, divide

[image]

I need to split(like divide) by **5**, however each value should balance maximum possible way to each part

***Example***

```
6= 3,3 is ok.  but 6= 5,1 is wrong
```

---

```
18= 5,5,4,4 is ok. but 18= 5,5,5,3 is wrong
```

---

```
21= 5,4,4,4,4 is ok. but 21= 5,5,5,5,1 is wrong
```

Comment: But what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do - do you want to generate all the correct arrangements of the valid numbers, or just be able to check if one particular arrangement is correct or incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying math for this is as follows. `Number have to split` will be split into repeats of two numbers. The **smaller number** is given by

```
=QUOTIENT(NUMBER_HAVE_TO_SPLIT,SPLIT_BY_PARTS)
```

and the **larger number** is given by

```
=QUOTIENT(NUMBER_HAVE_TO_SPLIT,SPLIT_BY_PARTS)+1
```

FYI the `QUOTIENT` worksheet function does integer division, e.g, `QUOTIENT(13,4)=3`.

The number of times the **larger number** is repeated is given by:

```
=MOD(NUMBER_HAVE_TO_SPLIT,SPLIT_BY_PARTS)
```

and the number of times the **smaller number** is repeated is given by:

```
=SPLIT_BY_PARTS - MOD(NUMBER_HAVE_TO_SPLIT,SPLIT_BY_PARTS)
```

The remaining task is to return the results in the formats you suggest. To get the comma-delimited format `3,4,4`:

1. Convert both **smaller number** and **larger number** to text using `TEXT(number,0)`
2. Prepend each with a comma to give the strings `,3` and `,4`
3. Use the `REPT` function to repeat each the appropriate number of times to give `,3` and `,4,4`
4. Concatenate these two strings and use `SUBSTITUTE` to remove the first comma

A somewhat messy formula to accomplish the above is:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REPT(","&TEXT(QUOTIENT(A2,B2),"0"),B2-MOD(A2,B2))&REPT(","&TEXT(QUOTIENT(A2,B2)+1,"0"),MOD(A2,B2)),",","",1)
```

where `NUMBER_HAVE_TO_SPLIT` and `SPLIT_BY_PARTS` are in `A2` and `B2`, respectively.

A formula to generate the `3=1 and 4=2` format is

```
=TEXT(QUOTIENT(A2,B2),0)&"="&TEXT(B2-MOD(A2,B2),"0")&IF(MOD(A2,B2)>0," and "&TEXT(QUOTIENT(A2,B2)+1,0)&"="&TEXT(MOD(A2,B2),"0"),"")
```

Comment: Thank you.... very much..., my problem is now solved from this formula. my apologies for poor English. however you perfectly understood what i mean to explain. thanks all other members also for try to help me